# How can I recover an Exodus Wallet with lost password?

Tags: wallet-recovery, lost-wallet, exodus

Four years ago, I bought Bitcoin for my son. I bought this via Coinbase which I then transferred to an Exodus Wallet. I lost my Exodus password. I saved a string with 34 characters containing a mixture of numbers, upper case and lower case letters. I can't remember what this was for. Is there anything I can do to recover my 12 word phrase?

Comment: if you still have the computer where you installed the Exodus wallet, maybe you can recover it.

Comment: If you have Exodus Keystore or Json wile so you can open it easily. Do you have old device you used to create Exodus ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to search for the seed.seco file which should be in your appdata/roaming folder named exodus.wallet
this file cointains your encrypted 12 word seed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a 34-letter string (`1...`) is an address which can only be used to track the balance. This won't help in spending those.